# How to get "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" Permission Google Drive API for android?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play

I want to access Google Drive API for Android using Play Service.

Play Service is currently not providing permission for "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive".

How can we get this permission using Play Service on Android?

Comment: You can't. Use the rest API.

Comment: You should use the drive.file scope.  This scope is greatly preferred by users, as they can control what your app has access to.

Comment: @CherylSimon, Is there a solution I don't know about, if the Drive objects are created by a different (non-Android) app?

Comment: @seanpj What do you mean by a different app?  If it is the web/ios version of the same app, they should share the same developer console configuration, and thus share access to the same set of files.  Otherwise, the user needs to grant access to the specific app using the file picker.

Comment: @CherylSimon By 'a different app', I meant for instance 'drive.google.com' (different app, same user). It allows a user to CRUD Drive objects, but on Android (GDAA) he/she has only the file picker option right?

Comment: @CherylSimon. Here's a specific example: A Docs Sheet (spreadsheet) with a script (xxx.gs) that creates a Drive file (haven't tried yet, hope it's possible). I don't remember any involvement of developers console when I created the script. How would a GDAA Android App access such a file?

Comment: @seanpj An published Apps Script project does have a developer console project, it just got created for you in the background.  See this page for details, including how to switch it to a different dev console project https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization